# Error while using shell script to copy lines to a file using cygwin

Tags: shell, cygwin

I am trying to copy few lines to another file .bashrc using shell script and cygwin terminal.The lines are :

```
echo "export DEVENVHOME=${DEVENVHOME:-$workarea/devenv.x}" >> .bashrc
```

I am writing command :

```
 workarea="/home/WORKAREA" sh script1.sh
```

But the output on .bashrc is :

```
  export DEVENVHOME=workarea/devenv.x
```

But i want the copy line

```
   export DEVENVHOME=${DEVENVHOME:-$workarea/devenv.x}
```

in .bashrc where $workarea should be replaced by the workarea provided as argument on cygwin terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes suppress substitution.

```
echo '...' >> ...
```

Comment: I wrote accordingly, But now the $workarea variable is also not being replaced by argument provided through cygwin terminal.

Comment: Your `.bashrc` is not interactive with your current shell environment since it is loaded when your session starts, so it won't pick up variables set later.  You would also need to specify the `$workarea` variable in your `.bashrc` as well in order for this to work as intended, or if you do want it to interact with your current shell environment, you would need to use some form of `eval` -- for instance if I want to load my user's .bashrc settings in my root shell, I would use `eval "$(cat /home/username/.bashrc)"`.  Experiment around with `eval` a bit, and you can get what you're looking for.